# How to determine daily accumlated values in mysql for each sample?

Tags: mysql, join

I've got a mysql table that has a running total:

```
+---------------------+--------+
| Timestamp           | Total  |
+---------------------+--------+
| 2012-07-04 05:35:00 |  1.280 | 1.280-1.280 = 0
| 2012-07-04 09:25:00 |  2.173 | 2.173-1.280 = 0.893
| 2012-07-04 09:30:00 |  2.219 | 2.219-1.280 = 0.939
| 2012-07-04 15:00:00 |  7.778 | 7.778-1.280 = 6.498
| 2012-07-04 21:05:00 | 13.032 | 13.032-1.280 = 11.752
| 2012-07-04 22:00:00 | 13.033 | 13.033-1.280 = 11.753
| 2012-07-05 05:20:00 | 13.033 | 13.033-13.033 = 0
| 2012-07-05 07:10:00 | 13.140 | 13.140-13.033 = 0.107
| 2012-07-05 10:15:00 | 14.993 | 14.993-13.033 = 1.960
| 2012-07-05 11:35:00 | 16.870 | 16.870-13.033 = 3.837
+---------------------+--------+
```

What I'm looking for is a query that determines the aggregated daily increase for each interval.
I've tried to show the desired outcome as well as the calculation behind each row. I've tried already several things with a join, but somehow I fail to determine what the starting value for each day is.

Thanks.

Comment: You name a column or result a `timestamp`, but it shows `dateTime` (`%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s`)

Comment: @w0051977: I've tried to address this with a subquery, but that worked only for a single day and not for multiple days: <snip> where DATE(TimeStamp) = CURDATE() order by Total ASC limit 1) <snip>

Comment: @arnoudhgz: Yes, I know that the output shows a formatted timestamp. I just tried to demonstrate that the column was based on timestamps which are not always at a regular interval or starttime. If the latter was the case I could have searched for a particular timestamp for each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't vouch for the efficiency of this query, but it does get you the results you are looking for:

```
SELECT t1.`Timestamp`, t1.`Total`, 
      CASE WHEN t1.`timestamp` =
            (SELECT MIN(t2.`Timestamp`)
             FROM myTable t2 
             WHERE DATE(t2.`Timestamp`)=DATE(t1.`Timestamp`)) 
        THEN 0
        ELSE t1.`Total` - (SELECT MIN(t3.`Total`)
              FROM myTable t3
              WHERE DATE(t3.`Timestamp`)=DATE(t1.`Timestamp`))         
        END AS Diff
FROM myTable t1
ORDER BY `Timestamp`
```

**Alternate Solution (more efficient I think)**

```
SELECT  t1.`Timestamp`, t1.`Total`, (t1.`Total` - d1.MinVal) diff
FROM myTable t1 
  INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT DATE(`Timestamp`) ts_date,
             MIN(`Total`) AS MinVal
      FROM myTable
      GROUP BY ts_date) d1
  ON DATE(t1.`Timestamp`) = d1.ts_date
```

Comment: Thanks this is very useful. The second solution seems indeed the preferred solution as it seems to use less system resources.